# How to create new category that lists new products added in the last 7 days

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, cron-task

I need to display products which added in last 7 days in a new category called `New In`. When I import products I will add all the products to category `New In` and it should automatically delete products that old more than 7 days automatically. I have searched for this but did not find a solution, can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a cron job with following code replace your "YOUR NEW IN CATEGORY ID"

```
set_time_limit(0);
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$to = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($to)));


//Load product model collecttion filtered by sale attribute
$proCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addfieldtofilter('created_at', array('lt' => $from));


foreach ($proCollection as $product) {
    $ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (($key = array_search(YOUR NEW IN CATEGORY ID, $ids)) !== false) {
        unset($ids[$key]);
        $product->setCategoryIds($ids);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```